# Monaca <ons> tab bar not showing up

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I am new to ONsen UI and have been developing templates in Monaca using regular JS and Jquery. When I use any of the  tags or properties nothing shows up in monaca. Its a plain blank page. Here is a sample code for a Tabbed view.This is the same for  and for most properties. Am I missing something here ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./components/loader.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/onsenui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/onsenui.js">

    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-tabbar>
        <ons-tab icon="home" label="Home" page="page1.html" active="true"></ons-tab>
        <ons-tab icon="comment" label="Comments" page="page2.html"></ons-tab>
        <ons-tab icon="gear" label="Settings" page="page3.html"></ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Made a stupid error. Should add these  <script src="./js/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="./js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also, usually in Monaca you add Onsen UI in `Config > Manage JS/CSS components`. Check that you are not including it twice.

Comment: If it helps, Monaca have a simple demo application that shows a tabbar working here: https://docs.monaca.io/en/sampleapp/samples/onsen_ui_tabbar_navigator/